# Need help understanding REST API endpoints

Tags: api, http, rest

I don't quite grok how to sensibly structure a REST (or REST-like) API.

Imagine an API for creating and sending out newsletter emails.  You might have the following nouns/resources: newsletters (subject, body, etc.), mailing lists (collections of recipients), and recipients (email addresses and associated data).

So you could use PUT to create a resource and be returned its ID:

```
/newsletter
/list
/user
```

You could obtain information on a resource using GET:

```
/newsletter/[id]
/list/[id]
/user/[id]
```

You can update an existing resource using PATCH (or should this be POST?):

```
/newsletter/[id]
/list/[id]
/user/[id]
```

You can delete a resource using DELETE:

```
/newsletter/[id]
/list/[id]
/user/[id]
```

1. Is the above correct?
2. What endpoints are sensible for actions like sending a newsletter to a list, adding a user to a list?

Does the following make sense, and is it RESTfull?

```
/newsletter/[newsletter_id]/send/[mailinglist_id]
/list/[list_id]/add/[user_id]
/list/[list_id]/remove/[user_id]
```

Is it redundant or unhelpful to have `list/[id]/add/[id]` and `list/[id]/remove/[id]` endpoints for lists, when users could be added or removed via PATCH at `/list/[id]` ?

What about searching for a users' ID via a property like email address or name?  Or getting a list via an identifier like its name or when it was created?

Answer (score 8):

You pretty much nailed it, except with the `/list/[list_id]/add/[user_id]` and `/list/[list_id]/remove[user_id]`, because you have verbs in the URL - that is the purpose of the HTTP methods. Change them to, for example:

```
PUT (or POST) to /list/[list_id]/users/ for adding a user to the list
```

and

```
DELETE to /list/[list_id]/users/[user_id]
```

For search, I'd go with parameterized url for the list of resources, like:

```
/newsletter/?name=dfjkhskdfh
```

Comment: What about the "send" verb?

Answer (score 1):

These verbs are often confused:

1. To create an entity you use **POST**
2. To update - **PUT**

These things could be treated in the following way:

`POST /newsletters/[newsletter_id]/mailinglists/[mailinglist_id]/mailingfacts` - performs sending the letters, it's like adding a fact of mailing to the collection

`/lists/[list_id]/[user_id]` - adds a user to the list

`/lists/[list_id]/[user_id]` - deletes the user from the list.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it redundant or unhelpful to have `list/[id]/add/[id]` and `list/[id]/remove/[id]` endpoints for lists, when users could be added or removed via `PATCH` at `/list/[id]` ?

It is bad/unhelpful. One of the ideas of REST is that the end points are resources and not a Remote Procedure Call (RPC). `add` or `remove` is suggesting a procedure to call.

Further GET requests should be side-effect free, that is, they don't do any updates. [Further Roy Fielding explains GET as](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post):

> retrieval of information that should be a representation of some resource

So GET is only for retrieval, not for sending data (i.e. which user to add/remove).

The other very dangerous problem with `list/[id]/remove/[id]` is that if a spider or your test framework is going around your site it could start deleting items.